If $f$ is positive and continuous on $[a,b]$, prove there is a $c>0$ such that $f(x)\geq c$ on $[a,b]$
Many times, I try to understand problems visually, but I am confused how to envision this. Perhaps as a result, I do not know how to begin to answer this question. I would like to understand what this problem is representing visually and how to begin to write the proof. Thanks.

Let $f$ be a continuous function on $[a, b]$. If $f(x)>0$ for all $x\in [a, b]$. Prove there exists $c>0$ such that $f(x)\geq c$ for all $x\in [a, b]$.


Intuition is a good thing, but what matters in the end are the formal results. Which theorems do you know about continuous functions on closed intervals?

There is the extreme value theorem and the intermediate value theorem. By the definition of the IVT, I can suggest if ∃y s.t. f(a) ≤ y ≤ f(b) (or vice versa), then ∃c ∈ [a, b] s.t. f(c) = y. Though, how do I apply this theorem to the question?

Properties of the closed and bounded interval clearly matter.  If $f(x)=e^{-x^2}$ we have $f(x)>0$ for all $x\in \mathbb R$ yet the desired claim is false for the whole real line.  Do you know any relevant theorems about continuous functions on closed bounded sets?

This is a special case of the Extreme Value Theorem.

@Nicholas Try to use the fact that a continuous function on $[a,b]$ has a minimum.

All of the hints, visualizations, and other answers to this problem have been extremely helpful. I know comments are not generally supposed to be only about giving thanks, but in this case, it will as I internalize the information.

If $f(x)>0$ then $1/f(x)$ is continuous on $[a,b],$ hence $f$ is bounded. Let $1/f(x)\le M.$ Then $f(x)\ge {1\over M}.$

In terms of what to visualise for this result, there are two key points worth visualising.
Suppose that $f\colon I \to \mathbb R$ is continuous and $f(x)>0$ for all $x \in I$. Then the problem asks you to show that there is an $m>0$ with $f(x)\geq m$ for all $x \in I$ when $I$ is a closed interval, that is $I = [a,b]$ for some $a\leq b \in \mathbb R$.

The fact that the domain on which the continuous function $f$ is positive is a closed interval is essential: If you replace $[a,b]$, the domain of $f$, with $(a,b],[a,b)$ or $(a,b)$ the result is false -- translating and scaling appropriately, one can assume that $[a,b]=[0,1]$ and then $f_1(x)=x$ and $f_2(x) = 1-x$ give counterexamples for  $(0,1]$ and $[0,1)$ respectively.

Independently of the nature of the domain $I$, for any $c \in I$ the continuity of $f$ together with the fact that $f(c)>0$ guarantees that $f$ has a strictly positive lower bound near $c$: indeed the continuity of $f$ at $c$, taking $\epsilon= f(c)/2$ in the definition of the continuity, there is a $\delta_c>0$ such that if $x \in (c-\delta_c,c+\delta_c)\cap I$ then $f(x)>f(c)-f(c)/2 = f(c)/2$. Thus "near $c$" (i.e. within $\delta_c$ of $c$) the values of $f(x)$ are at least $f(c)/2$, and thus $f(c)/2$ provides a positive lower bound to the values of $f$ in an interval centred at $c$.


For each $c \in I$, let $J_c = (c-\delta_c, c+\delta_c)$, so that $f(x)>f(c)/2$ for all $x \in J_c\cap I$. Now if we could show that there is a finite set $\{c_1,\ldots,c_n\} \subseteq I$ such that $I= \bigcup_{i=1}^n J_{c_i}$, then $m=\min\{f(c_i)/2: 1\leq i \leq n\}$ is a positive lower bound for the values of $f$ on $I$.
When $I$ is a closed interval $[a,b]$, we can show that it is covered by finitely many of the intervals $\{J_c: c \in I\}$ as follows: Let
$$
B = \{d \in [a,b]: \exists c_1,\ldots, c_m \in I, [a,d] \subseteq \bigcup_{k=1}^m J_k\}
$$
Then $B$ is non-empty because $\{a\} \subset J_a$, and as $B \subseteq [a,b]$ it is bounded above, so that $\sup(B)$ exists. We claim that $s = \sup(B)\in B$ and that $s=b$. To see that $s \in B$, note that $s-\
\delta_s<s$ hence there is some $t \in B$ with $s-\delta_s <t\leq s$. But then there are finitely many points $c_1,\ldots,c_m$ such that $[a,t]\subseteq \bigcup_{k=1}^m J_{c_k}$. But then $[a,s]\subseteq \bigcup_{k=1}^m J_{c_k} \cup J_s$, and hence $s \in B$. Moreover, clearly $[s,s+\delta_s)\cap [a,b] \subseteq B$, hence since $s = \sup(B)$ we must have $s=b$.

The second point holds for $c$ in the domain of $f$ assuming $f$ is continuous and positive on its domain of definition as in the hypothesis of the question, with the appropriate modifications at the endpoints as noted in 2. If an endpoint is not in the domain where $f$ is continuous and positive, then obviously 2. does not hold, which was the reason for point 1 (which includes the example of $f(x)=x$ on $(0,1)$.)

Ah! I see what you were getting at now.

Visually the problem is saying that if the function lies above the $x$-axis on a closed interval, then it also lies above (but potentially touches) some line $y=c$ for some $c>0$. It is important that this interval is closed, as if we had an interval like $(a,b)$, then it could be the case that $f(x)$ gets arbitrarily close to $0$ as $x$ approaches one of the endpoints. However in the case where the interval is closed, this clearly cannot happen, as if it got arbitrarily close to $0$ as we approached the endpoints, then the function would have to actually equal $0$ there.
With this in mind, you can also realize that saying that there exists some $c>0$ such that $f(x)\geq c$ for all $x\in[a,b]$ is the same as saying that $f(x)$ does not get arbitrarily close to $0$ on the interval. Indeed to say that $f(x)$ can get arbitrarily close to $0$ on the interval would mathematically be to say that for any $c>0$ (representing some distance to $0$), we can find some $x\in[a,b]$ such that $f(x)<c$, i.e. for any distance to $0$, we can find some point on the interval where the function is closer to $0$ than that. In symbols this is
$$\forall c>0:\exists x\in[a,b]:f(x)<c.$$
Now observe that the negation of this is
$$\exists c>0:\forall x\in[a,b]:f(x)\geq c,$$
i.e. there exists some distance to $0$ for which no point gets us that close to it (which is exactly what the questions asks).
Now let us turn this idea into a proof. Suppose for a contradiction that this was not the case, i.e. that we could get arbitrarily close to $0$. To get arbitrarily close to $0$, we consider the distances $\frac{1}{n}$ for $n\geq1$, which get smaller and smaller as $n$ gets larger. More precisely for each $n\geq1$ we can find some point $x_n\in[a,b]$ such that
$$f(x_n)<\frac{1}{n}$$
(as we are assuming for a contradiction that we can always find some point getting us as close as we want). But this gives us a sequence $\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{Z}^+}$ in the interval $[a,b]$. Now ideally we would want this sequence to converge, so that we actually reach $0$ (as we get closer and closer), however there is no guarantee that this sequence actually converges. We thus appeal to Bolzano-Weierstrass' theorem, which guarantees us that, as we are in a closed interval, there is at least a subsequence which converges, i.e. we can find some subsequence $\{x_{n_k}\}_{k\in\mathbb{Z}^+}$ of the sequence which converges to some point $x\in[a,b]$. But then, as $f$ is a continuous function, it is the case that
$$0<f(x)=\lim_{k\to\infty}f(x_{n_k})\leq\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{1}{n_k}=0.$$
But saying that $0<0$ is a contradiction, and so our claim follows.

An alternative way to prove this would be to use the fact that a continuous function on a closed interval attains a minimum value. Indeed as $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, there exists some $x_m\in[a,b]$ such that $f(x)\geq f(x_m)$ for all $x\in[a,b]$. Now simply take $c=f(x_m)$. Then $f(x)\geq c$ for all $x\in[a,b]$, and $c>0$ as the function only takes positive values.

A good starting visual for a continuous function $f(x)$ on a closed interval $[a,b]$ is a piece of string spanning the interval $[a,b]$.
The key points are:

The string is not broken anywhere. No matter how microscopically far in you zoom on the string, it remains a single strand. It does not have a gap, it does not shoot off to infinity and return, it's a regular old string. This is an intuitive version of the delta-epsilon meaning of continuity - you are guaranteed that the string must be within some distance of the neighboring string as you zoom in, at every point in the interval.

We typically presume single-valued functions, so that $f(x)$ may not take two values simultaneously. This means the string has no loops, and particularly that if you place a stick or ruler vertically, that the ruler hits the string one and only one time in the entire interval $[a,b]$.


Now just have the string above some arbitrary $y=0$, and also with its endpoints on some real values at $[a,b]$, and you have your visual. Your job is to prove the string can only go so high, so that there is some value of $y$ that it does not pass.

It is a well known theorem that$f$ continuous on a compact implies $f$ atteints its maximum and minimum. In other words there exist $m,M\in[a,b]$ (non necessarily unique) such that
$f(m)\le f(x)\le f(M)$ for all $x$: Since $f(m)\gt0$ by definition, if we take $0\lt c\le f(m)$ we are done.
